# subprocess.Popen getting through error when run from cron

Tags: python

I have got the below script, this works fine when i run this from command line however when i put the same script to execute through cron it throws me the error.

My code

```
import subprocess
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from datetime import date as dt

sites = ('dc1', 'dc2', 'dc3')

ping_cmd = ['fping', '-C', '1']

for site in sites:

    # get_info is environment specific script which pulls certain details for the servers.
    cmd1 = ['get_info', '-c', '-H', "install%", '-s', site]
    server_list = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip().split(',')
    not_alive = ''

    if len(server_list):
        for i in server_list:
            server_status = subprocess.Popen(['fping', '-C', '1', '-q', i], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            out, err = server_status.communicate()
            if server_status.returncode != 0:
                not_alive += i + '\n'

current_time = dt.today().strftime("%F")
from_add = 'noreply@test.com'
to_add = 'user@test.com'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = from_add
msg['To'] = to_add
msg['Cc'] = cc_add
msg['Subject'] = 'Unreachable Install Boxes on ' + current_time
# Attach the email body to MIMEMultipart object
msg.attach(MIMEText(not_alive, 'plain'))
body = msg.as_string()

server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.sendmail(from_add, [to_add, cc_add], body)
server.quit()
```

Above works just fine when run like this `/usr/bin/python2 pingtest.py`

However when i schedule the same script like this `08 * * * * /usr/bin/python2 /apps/rbhanot/pingtest.py` in cron i get the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/apps/nttech/rbhanot/Documents/PythonPrograms/tower-scripts/pingtest.py", line 28, in <module>
    server_list = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Where is `get_info`? Make sure it's in a location included in the PATH variable your crontab is run with (you can put environment variable definitions at the top of your crontab, before the job specifications, in `key=value` form). This is given in the 2rd (unaccepted) answer to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try mentioning the full path to the environment script.

**Replace**

```
cmd1 = ['get_info', '-c', '-H', "install%", '-s', site]
```

**to**

```
cmd1 = ['FULL_PATH/get_info', '-c', '-H', "install%", '-s', site]
```

Comment: Or just set a reasonable `PATH` in your crontab file. Set `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin` (if the `get_info` command is in `/usr/local/bin`), and there you are, without needing to modify any of the scripts that cron invokes (and thereby reduce their portability across environments -- as soon as you make your script run `/usr/local/bin/get_info`, it won't work somewhere `get_info` is in `/opt/local/bin`; but let the PATH be locally configured and the script can work anywhere).